# SSIS | Dealing with Columns in a CSV File That Keep Changing Order

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a package in SSIS that is using a flat file connection to connect to a CSV file. I built it based on a template file that I received from someone, and to keep things simple, it has a header row showing ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC (in that order). The package is being used for automation purposes to pull in a file each day and ingest the contents of it into a SQL table.

The issue I am running into is that all of the files that I receive daily seem to have the header row data in a different order, and it is messing up the ingestion process. For example: I receive a file that has ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnA (in that order) and SSIS (I assume) is just noticing that there is 3 columns in total and accepts the file, so when it comes time to push to SQL, the data from each column is going into the wrong column withing SQL since the ordering matters.

Has anyone ever ran into this issue and has found a way around it?

If I need to explain more, I am more than willing to. Been trying to figure this out for a while.

Comment: Does this answer your question?   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e7282a56-ba61-4177-a11d-fcb7b77b0a74/import-flat-file-which-has-changing-column-order-using-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Does the file include the column headers? If those are present you could check on those. Best practice is to have a good chat with the party sending the data.